# Text not wrapping on column boundary

Tags: debugging

I am trying to render a LaTeX project and the words are spilling over the column boundary. What could be the reason for this? I thought that the class library took care of these issues.

For example:

```
....... yelloW|    |second column yellow
..........blue|    |second column blue
...........green   |second column green
........orange|    |second column orange
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It would be great if you could provide a Minimum Working Example [(MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to help contributors help you to solve your case.

Answer (score 1):

In small columns it can be difficult to format the text. In such cases use

```
some other text ...

\begin{sloppypar}
The test which produces overful hboxes ...
\end{sloppypar}

some more text ...
```